# Formatting Disk? Clean new Ubuntu Setup on a messed up one

Tags: boot, partitioning

After messing up my Ubuntu 14.04 due to a forced shutdown DURING the update-process to 16.04, my System was completly messed up. Thanks to this forum, i was able to save at least my data to a external drive by using a live session.

Now i want to get things right. Will re-installing Ubuntu 16.04 from a bootable cd do or should i consider wiping clean the laptops harddrive by formatting them before? If yes, how would i do this?

Laptop: lenovo ThinkPad Edge E520, confirmed by canonical (14.04 did run well)

Thanks,
WZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer for ubuntu will offer you various options (install alongside current OS, overwrite current OS, other,...)

If you want to be sure, I would recommend picking 'other' and formatting any partitions you feel unsure about.